# How to add int[] to shared memory?

Tags: c, shared-memory

I haven't used C for ages and I have some problems with shared memory. I try to share table int[] beetwen two process. This is piece of code:

```
  //[..]
    void error_out(const char *msg)
{ 
    perror(msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int r;
    const char *memname = "/mymem";
    const size_t region_size = 10* sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
    int fd = shm_open(memname, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_RDWR, 0666);
    if (fd == -1) error_out("shm_open");

    r = ftruncate(fd, region_size);
    if (r != 0) error_out("ftruncate");

    int ptr[10];
    *ptr =mmap(0, region_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (ptr == MAP_FAILED) error_out("mmap");

    close(fd);
    pid_t pid = fork();
    ptr[5]=1;

    if (pid == 0) {
        ptr[5]=6;
        exit(0);
    }   
    else {
        int status;
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        printf("child wrote %d\n", (int *) ptr[5]);

    }
    r = munmap(ptr, region_size);
    if (r != 0)
     error_out("munmap");
    r = shm_unlink(memname);
    if (r != 0)
     error_out("shm_unlink");

    return 0;
}
    //[...] it's no whole code
```

I got:

> child wrote 1
>
> munmap: Invalid argument

Compiler returns some warning about cast, but i think this doesn't impact on effect.

Comment: We don't need to see your entire program, but we *do* generally expect a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: `int *ptr[10]` is an array of 10 pointers.  Probably not what you meant.

Comment: You probably mean `int *ptr;` then `ptr = mmap(...);`  Consider what the warning said!

Comment: @cdarke I can't use IPC, only POSIX.

Comment: After your last edit - `int ptr[10]` means that `ptr` is a pointer to the first element of an array on the stack.  `mmap()` returns a pointer which (by using `*ptr`) you are placing in the first element (depending on the size of an `int` and a pointer) of the array.

Comment: @cdarke Is possibile to share table beetwen 2 process using mmap()?

Comment: @Xalion: Lots of the functionality in POSIX is about IPC.  "I can't use IPC; I can only use POSIX" is practically meaningless.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it's instruction from my professor... "POSIX only, SysV - not allowed"

Comment: That’s meaningless.  POSIX includes the System V IPC.  If he said “POSIX except for the System V IPC”, then it would be meaningful.  But that’s quite different from what you said he said.

Comment: @Xalion:  you asked about sharing mapped memory areas between processes.  The answer is yes, but they can only share simply if they are both reading.  If one is writing then you need to use some form of locking, typically using a semaphore (sometimes two are required).  That would be the same if you were using shared memory segments.

Comment: Your code contains: `*ptr = mmap(0, region_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (ptr == MAP_FAILED)`.  You just set `ptr[0]` aka `*ptr` to the result of `mmap()`; there is no way that `ptr` is ever going to equal `MAP_FAILED`.  You could test `*ptr` or `ptr[0]` to see whether that is `MAP_FAILED`.  You are not going to map `ptr` into shared memory.  You can create yourself a pointer into shared memory.  So you might do better with `int *ptr = mmap(…); if (ptr == MAP_FAILED) …error…;` and then use `ptr` as the pointer to the start of the array in shared memory.\